# Count url shares on Facebook no longer work on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, url

I have been using the following code to get Facebook shares for URLs, and show them on my website. It worked very well until a few days ago. Does FB changed anything in the Graph? Do you have any solutions to solve the problem.

```
$url='https://mywebsite.com/a/101';
$fb='https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$url;
$fbjson=file_get_contents($fb);
$fbobj = json_decode($fbjson);
$fbshares=$fbobj->{'shares'};
echo $fbshares;
```

Note, when I use the url address I see the url shares count, eg.
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://mywebsite.com/a/101
Gives me the following result:

```
{
"https://mywebsite.com/a/101": {
"id": "https://mywebsite.com/a/101",
"shares": 44
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little changes I saw,
try this:

```
$url='https://sahafyonline.com/blog/101';
$fb='https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$url;
$fbjson=file_get_contents($fb);
$fbobj = json_decode($fbjson);
print_r($fbobj);
$fbshares=$fbobj->$url->{'shares'};
echo $fbshares;
```

Comment: Great (y), Thank you :)